# How to share a scoped service with a component inside an MdDialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an app with an *AppComponent* parent, and a *ProductComponent* child. In the *ProductComponent*, I have provided a service because I want the service to be available only within the *ProductComponent* scope and below (for any future grandchild components). I do not want to provide the service globally at the root scope of NgModule.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-product',
  providers: [ MyService ],
  ...
```

My *DialogComponent* is dependent on the service. But when I open a dialog from *ProductComponent*...

```
export class ProductComponent {
  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }  
}
```

...I get an exception:
**Error: No provider for MyService**

How can I forward the provided service from *ProductComponent* to the *DialogComponent*?

Please see my minimal [Plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/nZgQhc8KtcvkQATwPkZ8?p=preview) that shows the problem.

Comment: The exception was because you commented out the `providers` in your `AppModule`

Comment: @Edric, the commented part of the Plunker sample was intentional. If you uncomment it, you will end up with two instances of the service. I only want one single shared service that is provided for the _ProductComponent_ and below in the visual tree. The question is how the _ProductComponent_ can make the service available for the _DialogComponent_ when opening it within an MdDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue after finding an [identical issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2374) described on GitHub.

You need to pass an *MdDialogConfig* to the `dialog.open` function setting *viewContainerRef*, like so:

```
openDialog() {
  let config = new MdDialogConfig();
  config.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);
}
```

Now the *DialogComponent* will get its dependent services injected from the parent *ProductComponent*. I have a new [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6uI6YYJBKmoCU3zsSRjf?p=preview) showing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the service in your dialog component as well.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  providers: [ MyService ],
  template: `<div>Today's lottery number is {{service.lotteryNumber}}.</div>`,
})
export class DialogComponent {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }
}
```

Please have a look at the changed plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/feYrKfG1CfW785mDERCv?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With your solution, I do not get an exception, which is great. However, is the service really shared? It seem to be two instances of the _MyService_ now. If you add `service.lotteryNumber = service.lotteryNumber + 1;` in both the constructor of _ProductComponent_ and _DialogComponent_, shouldn’t the lottery number then be 2?

Comment: In order to share your service just for `ProductComponent` and its children, what you can do is create a module for `ProductComponent` and then inject a singleton from it. If my words here sounds confusing, please have a look at the updated plunker in the answer.

Comment: It is now working as I expected, great! Following your updated Plunker, I conclude that for dialogs any dependent shared service must be provided at the NgModule scope and that there is no way to share a service from a deeper level. In my real world app it will be difficult to break out the particular part into its own module, but that is another issue. If no one else brings an even better solution, I will mark your post as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thats all the help that I could provide. Lets hope that someone else also comes up with some solution so that I could also get to learn something new.